# Web-based garment builder

Tags: graphic-design

I'm after a 'garment builder' - the kind you find on custom T-shirt design website pages.

Preferably:

- Open source or otherwise able to link from an existing website,
- Able to upload custom images (garments and logos),
- Front, back and sleeve options.

Comment: So it could be a third-party hosted webservice (for example, displayed in an `iframe`)? Or do you need to integrate it with your site’s backend, e.g., some kind of API or library is required?

Comment: It wouldn't need integrating with the backend - so yes an iframe would probably do it.

Comment: What kind of garments do you need? Only T-shirt, or also socks/scarfs/trousers/etc?

Comment: Just t shirts and maybe trousers. We sell to construction contracters so hi via scarves might be stretch!

Answer (score 1):

[Essential Diagram for JavaScript](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/javascript/ejdiagram) supports creating any kind of diagram including a Gamrment/T shirt designer.

[Example](http://jsplayground.syncfusion.com/am1kcepg)

[image: Diagram JS T shirt designer]

The whole product is available for free through the [community license](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense) if you qualify (less than 1 million USD in revenue).

I work for Syncfusion.

Answer (score 0):

If you want do design your own shirt like this: http://www.spreadshirt.co.uk/design-your-own-t-shirt-C59

then you maybe need a tool like this: https://github.com/spreadshirt/spreadshirtapps/commit/7f1b4fd2f7a19d2aaccfcc5cbfc858eb93c0323f

I think this is maybe the page without the broken link. Anyway, it is the spreadshirt simplomat the other user told you to use. And it works.